# Should a non-empty subset $B$ of $A$ be formally denoted $B\subseteq A\backslash\emptyset$ or $B\subseteq A\backslash\{\emptyset\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ be an arbitrary non-empty set. Then, by definition of the empty set, $\emptyset\subseteq A$. Consider now a non-empty subset $B\subseteq A$. In order to formally specify that the subset $B$ is non-empty, should I write $B\subseteq A\backslash \emptyset$ or $B\subseteq A\backslash\{\emptyset\}$?

To me, writing $B\subseteq A\backslash \emptyset$ seems more natural, for the emptyset is itself a set and thus the curly brackets seem redundant and incorrect. However, $B\subseteq A\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ also seems to have some intuitive appeal. **Can you please clarify which is the correct way of writing it and why?**

Comment: Why not simply $B \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to find the most concise and compact notation there is. Plus, I want to know which of the two is correct for the sake of knowledge and understanding.

Comment: Neither will work.  $B\subseteq A\setminus \emptyset$ just means that $B$ is a subset of the the set $A\setminus \emptyset$ (which, btw, is just the set $A$).  There's nothing to indicate $B$ can't be empty.  $B\subseteq A\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ simply says that $B$ is a subset of the set $ A\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ (which is the set of all the elements of $A$ that are not the empty set).  There is no proper and concise notation other than $B\ne \emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is correct: let $A:=\{1,2,3\}$; you can write $A-\{1,2\}$ but not "$A-\{\emptyset\}$" since $\emptyset \notin A$.

A good notation is
$$(B\subset A \text{ and } B\neq \emptyset )\iff B\in \mathcal{P}(A)- \{\emptyset\}$$where $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please elaborate on why is neither correct? Also, would $B\in\mathcal{P}(A)\backslash\{\emptyset\}$ be correct, then?

Comment: Neither is correct.  $B\subset A\setminus X$ indicates that $B$ can't have any of the elements of $X$.  It indicates the elements that $B$ *can't* have but not any of the elements $B$ *must* have.  So $B\subset A\setminus \emptyset$ will indicate that $B$ can't have any elements that the empty set has (which are none).  It doesn't in anyway indicate $B$ can't be empty.  And $B\subset A\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ indicates that $B$ is not allowed to have the emptyset as one of its elements.  That has nothing to do with $B$ being or not being the emptyset.

Comment: Should note that for all sets $X$ that $X \setminus \emptyset  = X$.  Because $X\setminus \emptyset = \{w\in X| w \not \in \emptyset\}$ but as $w \in \emptyset$ is impossible this is $\{w\in X\}= X$.